# Why aren't all my chosen selector options being removed?

Tags: javascript, dom, drop-down-menu

I'm working on an interactive form.

A user will select between two designs of tshirt: 'JS Puns' or 'I love JS'.

There are 6 total colors of t-shirt. If 'JS Puns' is selected, then only the first 3 colors will be available to be selected. Vice versa, if 'I love JS' is chosen as a design then only the last 3 colors will be selected. Specifcally, only the available colors will be visible in the color selection box.

For some reason, I am able to remove 1 or 2 of the colors but I am not able to delete all of the necessary 3.

Here is a snippet of the HTML I am working with:

```
<div>
          <label for="design">Design:</label>
          <select id="design" name="user_design">
            <option>Select Theme</option>
            <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
            <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
          <label for="color">Color:</label>
          <select id="color">
            <option value="cornflowerblue">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
            <option value="darkslategrey">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="gold">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="tomato">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
            <option value="steelblue">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="dimgrey">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
          </select>
        </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
// T-Shirt Info section of the form.
// For the T-Shirt color menu, only display the options that match the design selected in the "Design" menu. 
document.getElementById("design").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var tShirtMenu = document.getElementById('design');
    var tSelection = tShirtMenu.value;
    var tColor = document.getElementById('color');
    var colorSelection = tColor.options;

    if(tSelection === "js puns"){
        // If the user selects "Theme - JS Puns" then the color menu should only display "Cornflower Blue," "Dark Slate Grey," and "Gold."
        colorSelection.remove(3);
        colorSelection.remove(4);
        //colorSelection.remove(5);
    } else if (tSelection === "heart js"){
        // If the user selects "Theme - I ♥ JS" then the color menu should only display "Tomato," "Steel Blue," and "Dim Grey."
        colorSelection.remove(0);
        colorSelection.remove(1);
        colorSelection.remove(2);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: If you `.remove(0)`, which element do you think is then at index `0`? (Also, not what you're asking, but what if the user changes their selection back?)

Comment: Please leave the solution for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is really shitty... but I fixed it like this:

I deleted all the options in the HTML, but added in an extra: `<option><-- Please select a T-shirt theme</option>`

In my JS, I then reset the innerHTML of the colour select field based on which theme option was selected.

So it looked like this. Otherwise, as nnnnnn hinted towards, if I removed them, I'd have to somehow take them out and store them as temporary variables so I could reenter them again later.

So here it is.

Please let me know how I could have improved this:

```
// T-Shirt Info section of the form.
// For the T-Shirt color menu, only display the options that match the design selected in the "Design" menu. 
document.getElementById("design").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var tShirtMenu = document.getElementById('design');
    var tSelection = tShirtMenu.value;
    var tColor = document.getElementById('color');
    var colorSelection = tColor.options;

    if(tSelection === "selectTheme") {
        tColor.innerHTML = "<option><-- Please select a T-shirt theme</option>";

    } else if(tSelection === "js puns") {
        // If the user selects "Theme - JS Puns" then the color menu should only display "Cornflower Blue," "Dark Slate Grey," and "Gold."
        tColor.innerHTML = "<option value='cornflowerblue'>Cornflower Blue</option><option value='darkslategrey'>Dark Slate Grey</option><option value='gold'>Gold</option>"; 

    } else if(tSelection === "heart js") {
        // If the user selects "Theme - I ♥ JS" then the color menu should only display "Tomato," "Steel Blue," and "Dim Grey."
        tColor.innerHTML = "<option value='tomato'>Tomato</option><option value='steelblue'>Steel Blue</option><option value='dimgrey'>Dim Grey</option>";
    }
});
```